# Can I use two projects in same solution in Visual Studio using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web

I am trying to use two projects in same solution one is based on MVC and another is based on 3 Layer Architecture using C# and both of the projects are connected to each other. Is it possible anyone please tell me?
My first project is Website which is based on MVC and Second one is Web-based software i want to make this software in 3 Layer architecture after that i will connect this 3 layer software with my MVC website.

Comment: You create a 3rd project with the common code, so you don't have a circular reference

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of a solution is that it can contain multiple projects.
A naming convention for projects I follow is for example:

```
ProjectName.UI
ProjectName.Data
ProjectName.WebAPI
ProjectName.Mobile
ProjectName.UnitTest
```

For a proper three layer Architecture i would recommend a least that many projects.

Comment: I knew about it, one solution contain many projects but my question is can i use one MVC and another is 3 layer architecture project in same solution and it is possible to connect both project to each other